# Why can't I type in the windows search bar and can't access the language bar?

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro 64bit (Build 14393).

I used to press <kbd>⊞</kbd> and then type any command (say "sniping tool") and accessed that settings or program. But unfortunately, I can't do this right now! I've opened the "Windows Settings" window and tried to type in the "Find a setting" field. But it didn't take any input. Even now I'm pressing the <kbd>⊞</kbd> button on the keyboard but the start menu is not appearing. Or say I've opened the calculator (that came along the windows package) and tried to write anything with my keyboard, it doesn't work.

I really cannot understand why this is happening. The solution that has been provided in Microsoft customer support pages seemed not worked for me.

Even my language bar has also disappeared. I used to use this shortcut <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to access the language bar menu... but neither the language bar is showing nor the shortcut command is working. I went to control panel to see whether anything was changed... but it was okay. As I have to type in different languages, I need this shortcut barely to quickly switch between languages and I also need to see them changing. But the pop up which used to appear when <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> shortcut command was pressed and can see which language is getting selected, is not coming and I can't track which keyboard is active right now. I've to blindly press <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and expect the right language to be selected.

Have windows changed the shortcut in the latest update to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>? `This would be awful (if they have changed it).`

Can anyone help me why am I facing these problems?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing wrong with your keyboard? Did you tested your keyboard on other systems?

Comment: I haven't used any voice command to write this question nor this comment... I assure you...

Comment: Can you explain when it all started? After a reboot? Power outage? Changing some settings, updating?

Comment: I posted [a query](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/why-cant-i-type-in-the-windows-search-bar-and-cant/18297227-2beb-4f35-a7a9-edacc128bcad?tab=question&status=AllReplies#tabs) in answers.MS they responded with some recommendations that I've tried earlier. Even my mouse clicks are not working in the task bar. Before I posted this Q, I restarted the pc once again.

Comment: Please create a new user account and log in to it. Check if you experience the same problem. If not, that's a user specific problem usually caused by wrong permissions on your profile, or damaged per user configuration files. Please note that Windows Universal Apps (Start button is one of them too) are very likely to stop working due to the mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Press Windows + X keys on the keyboard, Open Command prompt (admin).
2.Execute this command : 
    PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
It will open the PowerShell window.
3. Now executing below command should fix it 
    Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers |Where-Object {$_.InstallLocation -like "*SystemApps*"} | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

If it helps please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Thank for your answer... I upgraded the windows to the latest build... which solved the problem... I'm sorry that I couldn't try your solution... many many thanks for your response.

Comment: I hope you could mark the anser as accepted as well , If it helped